# Checkboxes in system.xml file

Tags: magento-1.7, configuration

How do I use Checkboxes in system.xml file with bydefault checked? I want to configure my custom module with four check-boxes (left,right,top,bottom).
I am using this code, but it's display only unchecked checkboxes. When I am going to save settings it's save only last checkbox's value. Please see attached screen-shot.
[image]

```
<positions translate="label">
    <label>Show Position</label>
    <frontend_type>Checkboxes</frontend_type>
    <source_model>customodule/model</source_model>
    <sort_order>14</sort_order>
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
</positions>
```

I have created model function for this:

```
public function toOptionArray()
{
    return array('position' => 
        array('value' => 'left', 'label'=>Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Left')),
        array('value' => 'right', 'label'=>Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Right')),
        array('value' => 'top', 'label'=>Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Top')),
        array('value' => 'bottom', 'label'=>Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Bottom')),
    );
}
```

please suggest me what's code need to set and use these check-boxes?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Suggest reading through the Magento Wiki on system.xml setup. http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/admin/xml_structure_for_admin_configurations#defining_default_values

Comment: I read this Wiki but not much information about Checkboxes. default check not working and when I save with check all Checkboxes, only last one's value saved in database.
PS:sorry for my bed english

Comment: I'm not finding any good examples of how this is done in core, and I know I've looked at this previously. Maybe the best option is to use a multi-select instead.

Comment: It looks like when the html is created all the checkboxes have the same name so the last checked item will always be the one returned.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way of achieving what you need just through declaring the field in `system.xml`.
I really think the easiest way is to use a multiselect. It saves you the trouble.
But if you insist here is how you can do it. You will need a custom renderer for your config setting.
Declare your element like this:

```
<positions translate="label">
    <label>Show Position</label>
    <frontend_model>[module]/adminhtml_system_config_positions</frontend_model>
    <sort_order>14</sort_order>
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
</positions>
```

Now create the renderer: file `app/code/[codepool]/[Namespace]/[Module]/Block/Adminhtml/System/Config/Positions.php`

```
<?php
class [Namespace]_[Module]_Block_Adminhtml_System_Config_Positions extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form_Field{
    const CONFIG_PATH = 'path/to/positions'; //put here the full path from the config to your element
    protected $_values = null;
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->setTemplate('[namespace]_[module]/system/config/positions.phtml');
        return parent::_construct();
    }
    protected function _getElementHtml(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element)
    {
        $this->setNamePrefix($element->getName())
            ->setHtmlId($element->getHtmlId());
        return $this->_toHtml();
    }
    public function getValues(){
        $values = array();
        //get the available values (use the source model from your question)
        foreach (Mage::getSingleton('customodule/model')->toOptionArray() as $value){
            $values[$value['value']] = $value['label'];
        }
        return $values;
    }
    public function getIsChecked($name){
        return in_array($name, $this->getCheckedValues());
    }
    public function getCheckedValues(){
        if (is_null($this->_values)){
            $data = $this->getConfigData();
            if (isset($data[self::CONFIG_PATH])){
                $data = $data[self::CONFIG_PATH];
            }
            else{
                $data = '';
            }
            $this->_values = explode(',', $data);
        }
        return $this->_values;
    }
}
```

now the template to render your checkboxes. File `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/[namespace]_[module]/system/config/positions.phtml`

```
<input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $this->getNamePrefix() ?>" value="" /><!-- this is send if nothing is checked -->
<ul class="checkboxes">
    <?php foreach ($this->getValues() as $name => $label): ?>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $name?>" name="<?php echo $this->getNamePrefix() ?>[]" id="<?php echo $this->getHtmlId() . '_' . $name ?>"<?php echo ($this->getIsChecked($name) ? ' checked="checked"' : '') ?>/><label for="<?php echo $this->getHtmlId() . '_' . $name ?>">
                <?php echo $label ?>
            </label>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach;?>
</ul>
```

replace the placeholders `[Module]`, `[Namespace]` and `[codepool]` with your module values and give it a go.

This is how you can create any type of config element.

Comment: Great answer but multi-selects are a bad suggestion. They usually have the worst UX of any form control. A testament to this is Android's rendering of multi-selects as a list of checkboxes.

Comment: @Walf. I didn't suggest multi-selects. I said that it's easier to code it, because Magento had already a renderer for multi selects.

Comment: "I really think the easiest way is to use a multiselect. It saves you the trouble.
But if you insist…" Looks like a suggestion to me.

Comment: @Walf I offered 2 options, and expressed my opinion. One option is easier to implement, one looks nicer.

Comment: I like your solution, I just think steering people away from multi-selects is a good idea.